# Why does the await statement fire DocumentCompleted event again in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method to handle when browser has completed loading page.

```
private async void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    //Do something....
    await Task.Delay(7000);
    //Continue doing....
}
```

But instead of waiting for amount of time and then continue doing, program fire that event again.

I also noticed that the await method sometime cause the thread to pause, sometime it cause the thread to execute all the above sentences.

My question is how do I make sure that I execute all the code in that method before the event gets fired again, and to make sure the thread is waiting before continue doing?

Comment: What are you _really_ waiting for, though? Just a seven-second pause in a program doesn't seem especially useful.

Comment: Making user think that the application is doing something very useful and important! Maybe. :) @Nyerguds

Comment: @Nyerguds I need to check if the page finish loading or not, so I make the program wait.

Comment: @ThongVo That makes no sense. According to your description, that function should only _be_ called once the page finished loading.

Comment: @ThongVo: I am almost positive this problem has nothing to do with `await`. `WebBrowser` has a lot of odd behavioral quirks. Are you sure you're not just seeing the `DocumentCompleted` for multiple frames, or something like that?

Comment: @StephenCleary I'm sure that I only use WebBrowser in one frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some locking mechanism. For example:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private async void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {

        await _lock.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            //Do some stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle ex
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.Release();
        }
}
```

Problem is in some moment you can have a lot of event handler methods to execute. You should probably unbind it before next one is hited.